# Finding guid in onenote onetoc2 binary file

Tags: parsing, file-format, onenote, onenote-api, file-structure

According to the documentation provided by Microsoft the header structure of the oncetoc2 must be at the beginning of the file and must have the value

`{43FF2FA1-EFD9-4C76-9EE2-10EA5722765F}`

Characters Stripped

`43FF2FA1EFD94C769EE210EA5722765F`

Looking through the file with a hex editor I am unable to find a match for this string, nor can I find it after stripping all the characters and flipping the string. (Endianess?)

`F5672275AE012EE967C49DFE1AF2FF34`

Then I attempted to find a match with the hex equivalents of the string,
`7b34334646324641312d454644392d344337362d394545322d3130454135373232373635467d`

This can not be right, as it is much over 16 bytes.

I have been staring at this for a while and can't see what I am missing here. Not finding a pattern match with search tools.

What am I not doing right ?

OneNote onteoc2 file structure:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd906213(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question.
 I just had a look at the doc, being completely perplexed by it last time.
Here's what seems to be going on.
The first 16 bytes of the file
`A1 2F FF 43 D9 EF 76 4C 9E E2 10 EA 57 22 76 5F`
Lets break it down like this
 `A1 2F FF 43`                    flip it `43 FF 2F A1`
`D9 EF`                               flip it `EF D9`
`76 4C`                               flip it `4C 76`

`9E E2`                       dont flip it `9E E2`
`10 EA 57 22 76 5F` dont flip it `10 EA 57 22 76 5F`
And we get
{43F2FA1-EFD9-4C76-9EE2-10EA5722765F}

If you take bytes 48 to 63
`3F DD 9A 10 1B 91 F5 49 A5 D0 17 91 ED C8 AE D8`
And apply the same formula we get
{109ADD3F-911B-49F5-A5D0-1791EDC8AED8} - **guidFileFormat (16 bytes)**
I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I should have seen flipping the "chunks" :P